glmmTMB and nested random effects
I'm fairly new with stats and using glmmTMB and glmer, so bare with my explanation.
I'm analyzing data that is looking to see how different socioeconomic variables interact with each other and predict area of greenspace (continuous data) in a 3 way interaction. My socioeconomic data is scaled. I have 26 Sites and those Sites fall under 5 Classifications. Only one site can be under one classification. A classification can have many unique sites.
I have the following code:
mod29 = glmmTMB(PLAND_GreenspaceSum ~ (0 + Education + Med.Household_Income + Population + Underrepresented_Minorities)^3 + (1 |Classification)+ (1/Site), data = dat_2kmplandsocio_scaled) 

summary(mod29)
simulationOutput29 <- simulateResiduals(fittedModel = mod29, plot = F)
plot(simulationOutput29)

And it works great with diagnostic residuals looking good too.
enter image description here
My questions is, what is going on with the nested effects? When I have
(1 |Classification)+ (1/Site)

the code works. When I originally had
(1 |Classification)+ (1|Site)

the code worked, but i got less significant interactions, and my residuals don't look great.enter image description here
So I'm curious what is going on when
(1/Site) vs (1|Site)

I've been trying to search for it, and also within glmmTMB manal, but I can't find it. Anyone know what it means and the differences between a (|) and (/)?
Thank you so much
See questions and code above. I just need a way to defend my reasoning for the model I'm choosing and elements I have in it.

Hi, Adrianna! I ran some code similar to yours. In the expression "(1 |Classification)+ (1/Site)," the last term "(1/Site)" may not be having any effect. I don't think the term is valid. While it does not return an error, it does not add to the model either. If you are trying to specify a nested model (site nested within classification), the correct expression, as far as I know, should be "(1|Classification/Site)." However, I will let other experts weigh in on this.

Thank you this Suhas. I appreciate it. I'll correct my code. On a similar note, when I correct for glmmTMB do you or anyone have any recommendations for the model I trying to build? I need to use a glmm, I was leaning towards Gamily=gamma as the distribution. I'm just not sure how to fit the model best and get reasonable looking residuals.

Sorry, this question is outside my forte. I know it is possible using glmmTMB by specifying family = Gamma() but it requires an argument but I do not know what it should be.

I played around with removing (1|Site) just to see if it produces the same results of  (1/Site) and they do not have the same residual plots. Removing  (1|Site) deviates the QQ plot further. (1/Site) seems to improve the dispersion.
